# Navigation position in Control Panel Craft CMS 2.5

Tags: control-panel, navigation, position

The new position of the Control Panel navigation on the left side in Craft CMS 2.5 needs so much space and looks kind of wrong to me.

Is there any way to position it on the top like in pre 2.5 versions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't have thought so, it's to facilitate the new Commerce plugin (or at least that was the main driver) and ultimately is far more expandable over time.

The new interface is fluid too, rather than the previous fixed version. It took a little while to get used to but is now much better suited to the content input.

Comment: You're right Chris, i think i just have to get used to it. Thanks for the answer.